# IIS Connexion refused on localhost

Tags: http, iis, https, localhost

I have two Apps hosted on an IIS server (Windows server 2016):

- App 1 (ASP.NET CORE) which is accessible from outside the server by a URL.
- App 2 (ASP.NET WEB API) which is accessible only on the server on http://locahost:5000.

The scenario is the following:

1. The user requests ***App 1*** with a given URL (HTTPS).
2. ***App 1*** takes the payload from the request and sends it to ***App 2*** on localhost.
3. ***App 2*** responds to ***App 1*** which responds to the user.

Locally, the two apps running on two Visual Studio instances work fine (both running on localhost).

Since it's deployed on IIS, I can access both apps by their URLs but when I try the scenario above with postman, it gives me the following error:

> "statusCode": 500,
>       "message": "An unhandled error occurred",
>       "exception": "System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it) ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it\r\n   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n

It seems like ***App 1*** cannot reach ***App 2*** on localhost.

Any idea ?

Comment: “It seems like the App 1 cannot reach the App 2 on localhost.” Why cannot you attach a debugger to App 1 and dig further into the exception? That should lead you to more details.

Comment: The Apps are communicating fine when debugging, the error appears on a live server after publishing.

Comment: Reproduce the issue on your local machine and debug. I don't expect you to debug on the live server.